# Sub objects retrieved from mongodb is not intractable as a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with retrieve sub-documents from mongo.

First level values are accessible and correct but objects under array are not.

This is the mongoose models that a have:

```
const Player = mongoose.model('Player', new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {type: String, required:true},
    name: {type:String, required: true, unique: true},
    gems: {type: Number, default: 1100},
    avatarName: {type: String, default: 'whiteMan_blackHair_5'},
    miniGamesInfo: [new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {type: String, required: true },
            bestRecord: {type:Number, default:0 },
            //* the value zero (0) represents "undefined". Note that user can't send value zero.
            globalRank: {type: Number, default:0 },
            isInLeague: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            //* the value zero (0) represents "undefined". Note that user can't send value zero.
            leagueRank: {type: Number, default:0 },
            //* the value zero (-1) represents "not set until now".
        stars: {type: Number, default:-1, min:-1, max:5},
        perDayTries: {type: Number, default:0, min:0, max:10 }
    })]
}));
```

I saved some player info using the above model into MongoDB.
also, I have a routing like below:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const players = await Player.find();
    console.log(players);
    res.send(players);
});
```

When a client tries to get the players info, the server will handle the request using the above code. the client will receive the JSON object completely and perfectly and will be able to use all sub-objects and their fields...

BUT, in node js when I print the object in the console I'll see below:

```
[ { gems: 1100,
    avatarName: 'whiteMan_blackHair_5',
    _id: 5bc0af4137b4423870c93f5c,
    avatarNumber: 12,
    uid: '239dmc20mc3etc9347x276xs23i',
    name: 'Alex',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 },
  { gems: 1100,
    avatarName: 'whiteMan_blackHair_5',
    _id: 5bfe7f71fd094929344235da,
    uid: '239dmc20ft45r434u9i76xs23i',
    name: 'ned',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 },
  { gems: 1100,
    avatarName: 'whiteWoman_brownHair_4',
    _id: 5c0bd484a35b5e3f4473bcfc,
    uid: 'bd2972097e51a665d80bcea4fc0d3145ddd4251c',
    name: 'Peter',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 } ]
```

all "miniGameInfo" objects inside the "miniGamesInfo" array are un-intractable in node.
and when I trying to access sub-fields like below:

```
console.log(players[0].miniGamesInfo[0].name);
```

the console will shows "undefined".
nearly the same issues will occur when I trying to retrieve just some of the attributes from the player object(not all). a field like "name" will retrieve correctly but some sub-values like "title" or "bestRecord" returns badly. for example this code:

```
const players = await Player.find({}, {name: 1, 'miniGamesInfo.title': 1});
console.log(players);
```

will return in the console:

```
[ { _id: 5bc0af4137b4423870c93f5c,
    name: 'Alex',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: 5bfe7f71fd094929344235da,
    name: 'ned',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: 5c0bd484a35b5e3f4473bcfc,
    name: 'Peter',
    miniGamesInfo: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

while it returns the correct JSON data to the client:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5bc0af4137b4423870c93f5c",
        "name": "Alex",
        "miniGamesInfo": [
            {
                "title": "MatchPreviousCard"
            },
            {
                "title": "RememberTiles"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhichOneIsBigger"
            },
            {
                "title": "CountTaxies"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhatWasDeleted"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bfe7f71fd094929344235da",
        "name": "ned",
        "miniGamesInfo": [
            {
                "title": "MatchPreviousCard"
            },
            {
                "title": "RememberTiles"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhichOneIsBigger"
            },
            {
                "title": "CountTaxies"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhatWasDeleted"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c0bd484a35b5e3f4473bcfc",
        "name": "Peter",
        "miniGamesInfo": [
            {
                "title": "MatchPreviousCard"
            },
            {
                "title": "RememberTiles"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhichOneIsBigger"
            },
            {
                "title": "CountTaxies"
            },
            {
                "title": "WhatWasDeleted"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm kinda confused. but I guess the problem is with the way NODE JS parse the data.

Help, please. I'm stuck with it for 4 days.

Comment: What happens when you log `console.log(players[0].miniGamesInfo[0].title);` instead of `name`?

Comment: In addition please try `console.log(JSON.stringify(players));`

Comment: @Quali  Oh, it was my mistake. I should have tried `console.log(player[0].miniGamesInfo[0].title)` instead of `.name);` . It will return the correct data. the miniGame title that is `MatchPreviousCard`.

Comment: Also, when creating a projection like `{'miniGamesInfo.title': 1}`, mongodb/mongoose will keep the path of the object and will not directly lift title to the root level of the object. 

If this is what you want, you could either do it manually or use aggregation pipline with $replaceRoot: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/

Comment: @Quali Also When I try `console.log(JSON.stringify(players));` it will print all data as string in the console BUT when I try `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(players)));` again it will return objects like `[Object]`. but that's not a problem any more, because I can access object fields now. let me try a projection and assign the result to something.

Comment: @BenSower Yes, this is kinda what I want from the beginning and problems that fell in the way of that, lead me to this basic tests. Let me read the page and see if it can solve the problem.

Comment: @Armamedia no problem, just write, if you encounter more problems

Comment: I tested all of the cases in my project that I had a problem like this with them. And unfortunately, I should say that all the problems come from the exhaustion that I had because of the different complex situations that I got involved throw out the code. the projection also works well and instead of lifting variables like the `title` to the root level I assign them to another object's fields and use that one instead. ( but I also know, I should learn aggregation pipeline and use of $replaceRoot in near future. @BenSower Thank you. )

Comment: So, Is it better to delete the question? now that the main issue caused by my mistakes and confusions...?

Comment: You should keep the question, but answer it yourself listing the three problems mentioned above. This way, people with a similar problem might be helped. Also, asking questions should never be a problem :-)